# Spark : Efficient row replication

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

I am trying to replicate each row in my `Dataset` (600 000 rows) at least 10 000 times, affect an incremented variable to a column, and cache the dataset into memory, and for that I tried two solutions:

- Solution 1: `explode` but it is extremely slow due to [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-21657?attachmentOrder=desc) know bug.
- Solution 2: `flatmap` but I systematically get an OOM error because of GC overhead which leads to `MetadataFetchFailedException`.

The schema of my Dataset is as follows:

```
root
 |-- field1: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field3: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field4: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field5: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field6: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field7: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field8: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field9: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field10: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- value: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field11: string (nullable = true)
 |-- field12: double (nullable = true)
 |-- field13: integer (nullable = false)
```

I am partitioning my dataset (ncores * nexecutors * 4) times when loading the data into memory with:

> ncores = 15 and nexecutors = 20

I decided to increase the number of partitions 10 times in an attempt to reduce the size of each partition but obviously, that didn't help.

My questions are:

- What's the most efficient way to replicate each row of a `Dataset`
  using `Spark 2.1.1`?
- How can I get rid of OOM Errors if I stick with the flatMap alternative?

Comment: I didn't test so I write that in a comment, but did you try to do a cross-join with the index variable? or does it not satisfy the requirement?

Comment: It kinda worked even though the performance is quite terrible. Thank you very much !